# Two way data binding on Observable element

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I'd like to bind isSelected to an object wrapped in an observable. I tried alone (without the observable and it worked). 
However, here within my component, measure.isSelected always returns false, even when checkbox is checked.

```
          <tr *ngFor="let measure of criteriaSelectedMeasures$ | async ; let i = index">
            <td>{{measure.type}}</td>
            <td>{{measure.equipment}}</td>
            <td>{{measure.axis}}</td>
            <td>{{measure.direction}}</td>
            <td>{{measure.pr}}</td>
            <td>{{measure.section}}</td>
            <td>{{measure.agregation}}</td>
            <td>{{measure.measureType}}</td>
            <td>{{measure.qualification}}</td>
            <td>
              <p-checkbox name="criteria-measure-{{i}}" binary="true" [(ngModel)]="measure.isSelected"></p-checkbox>
            </td>
          </tr>
```

Inside my component :

```
this.criteriaSelectedMeasures$.subscribe(list => {
            this.store.dispatch(new AddMeasureDefinitionsAction(list.filter(m => m.isSelected))); <-- here isSelected is always false
        });
```

To me two way binding does not work here because async pipe or subscribing the observable creates a different object with another reference.

Am I right ? Is there another way to achieve this ? (maybe using ngModelChange ?)

Comment: tell me one thing, do you want to filter that list to have only those objects where `isSelected` equals to `true`, right?

Comment: It worked without observable because references are the same. Subscribe return new objects collection. Two way data binding won't bind it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you should not modify an object that comes from an observable. If you want to modify some particular measures then pass them directly as an array, then bind to them. Passing an observable to a component only makes sense if the component will present the data, without modifying them.

Observables are often not the best solutions in angular. In particular they only pass information one way and you should normally treat emitted objects as immutable, otherwise it's on the verge of hacking.

Also note that having two subscriptions (one with `|async` and one direct) is possibly not the best, unless your source is safeguarded against it, e.g. with [`shareReplay`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/shareReplay).

Another solution, although somewhat awkward, if you really want to pass objects in as observables, is to have an `@Output() measureSelectionChange` in your component where you pass e.g. measure id and the new selection state when the checkbox is clicked and something outside of your component is responsible for actually modifying the measure (and possibly pushing the modified set of measures again into your component).